# Bound on $|f(x)|^2 + |f'(x)|^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, contest-math

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a twice differentiable function satisfying
$$|f(x)|^2\le  a$$ and $$|f'(x)|^2 + |f''(x)|^2\le  b$$ for all real $x$,
where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants.
Prove that
$|f(x)|^2 + |f'(x)|^2\le  \max(a, b)$ for all real $x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the supremum of $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2$, note that
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2
&\le|f(x)|^2+\left(|f'(x)|^2+|f''(x)|^2\right)\\
&\le a+b\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
so $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2$ is bounded. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2\right)
&=2f(x)f'(x)+2f'(x)f''(x)\\
&=2f'(x)\left(f(x)+f''(x)\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
1. If $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2$ reaches a maximum, either $f'(x)=0$ or $f(x)=-f''(x)$.

$\quad$a. If $f'(x)=0$, then $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2=|f(x)|^2\le a$.

$\quad$b. If $f(x)=-f''(x)$, then $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2=|f'(x)|^2+|f''(x)|^2\le b$.

2. If $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2$ doesn't attain its maximum, then either

$\quad$a. there is a sequence of increasing local maxima as $x\to\infty$ or $x\to-\infty$, or

$\quad$b. eventually, it monotonically increases to its maximum as $x\to\infty$ or $x\to-\infty$.

In case 2a, apply 1. to each local maximum.

In case 2b, the mean value theorem says that there is a sequence $x_n\to\infty$ or $x_n\to-\infty$ so that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(|f(x_n)|^2+|f'(x_n)|^2\right)\to0$ as $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2$ increases to its supremum. Thus, by $(2)$, eventually $\left|f'(x_n)(f(x_n)+f''(x_n))\right|\le\epsilon^2$. Then either $\left|f'(x_n)\right|\le\epsilon$ or $\left|f(x_n)+f''(x_n)\right|\le\epsilon$.

$\quad$c. If $|f'(x_n)|\le\epsilon$, then $|f(x_n)|^2+|f'(x_n)|^2\le a+\epsilon^2$.

$\quad$d. If $|f(x_n)+f''(x_n)|\le\epsilon$, then
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x_n)|^2+|f'(x_n)|^2
&\le|f'(x_n)|^2+|f''(x_n)|^2+|f(x_n)+f''(x_n)|\,|f(x_n)-f''(x_n)|\\
&\le b+(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we are done.

Comment: How do we ensure that these points give a maximum and not a minimum?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, was that used in robjohn's solution? As long as the function reaches its maximum, the derivative would be 0 at that point.

Comment: Thanks robjohn for the detailed explanation. Now things are clear without any ambiguities.

Comment: @Sanchez: I wanted to ask why does derivative being zero ensure a maximum. As far as I am aware a zero derivative does not guarantee a extremum. However robjhohn updated his answer handling all the cases and there is no further issue here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: What I had said is that if there were a maximum, the derivative would be $0$. I never said that the derivative being zero implied a maximum, even before the edit.

Comment: Why does $f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x))\to 0$ imply that $f'(x)\to 0$ or $f(x)+f''(x)\to 0$?

Comment: @detnvvp: I have made the final part of the argument more explicit. Let me know if you still have concerns.

Comment: @robjohn: sorry! perhaps there has been some confusion / misinterpretation on my part. In the initial answer you treated the case 1) and i was thinking as to why only the case of maximum was possible. Before i could put my thoughts clearly, you gave the complete answer handling all the cases.

Comment: @robjohn: Still, you have a product being less than or equal to $\varepsilon^2$; this does not necessarily imply that each one of the factors is bounded by $\varepsilon$. What if, for example, for some $x$ you have that $|f'(x)|=1$ and $|f(x)+f''(x)|=\varepsilon^2$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: neither minimum nor maximum need be attained. For example, $f(x)=\tanh(x/2)$, where $a=1$ and $b=\frac14$, but $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2\lt1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @detnvvp: If $ab\le\epsilon^2$, then either $a\le\epsilon$ or $b\le\epsilon$. If $a\gt\epsilon$ and $b\gt\epsilon$, then $ab\gt\epsilon^2$.

Comment: Yes, but, what ensures that both $|f'(x)|$ and $|f(x)+f''(x)|$ are both less than $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @detnvvp: I am not assuming that both are less than $\epsilon$, only one. That is why I handle two cases.

Comment: Oh, you are right! Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: robjohn: could you elaborate the part using the mean value theorem (case 2b)? Thanks.

Comment: @YifengXu: I have adjusted the argument not to draw too much from the MVT. The sequence is all that is needed since $|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2$ is increasing.

Comment: Which version of the MVT are you referring to? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem I haven't seen your version with sequences and supremum before...

Comment: @YifengXu: Since $g(x)=|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2$ is monotonically increasing to its finite supremum, the MVT says there  is an $x_k\in[k,k+1]$ such that $g'(x_k)=g(k+1)-g(k)\to0$. If you wonder why $g(k+1)-g(k)\to0$, note that $\sum\limits_k(g(k+1)-g(k))$ is eventually a bounded sum of positive numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Or $0=\lim g(k+1) - \lim g(k) = \lim [g(k+1)-g(k)]$